# SUSY commuting with Poincaré

Tags: supersymmetry, poincare-symmetry

All books on supersymmetry begin with the Coleman-Mandula theorem and its extension to the graded algebras. Assume, however, that we are OK with the symmetry algebra of internal field symmetries $G$ being commuting with the Poincare algebra. Can such algebra be graded?

To put it simple. Let us have a multiplet of fields of different spins. What stops us from designing SUSY transformations which would not affect the spatial dependence of the fields but would rather just rotate the fields into each other? (much like in $O(N)$ or $CP(N)$ models but with components having different spins) Yes, the anti-commutator of $Q$s has to be bosonic. Can we set all those equal to zero and still have something non-trivial?

Comment: What do you mean by "*Assume, however, that we are OK with the symmetry algebra of internal field symmetries G being commuting with the Poincare algebra.*"? The fact that $G$ commutes with P. is part of the conclusions we draw from Coleman-Mandula (or Haag-Łopuszański-Sohnius). Why should we assume that it holds, when we have a theorem that guarantees it does? Note also that Coleman-Mandula and friends is about the $S$ matrix. These theorems say nothing about the fields, so what do you mean by the "*algebra of internal field symmetries*"

Comment: I think I made a mistake, thanks. Of course the algebra of internal symmetries does commute with the Poincare algebra. My question is why the susy algebra cannot work in a similar manner. Why can't we have just a bunch of Qs, all anticommuting with each other to zero and commuting with Poincare generators to zero as well.

Comment: Are you asking if the internal symmetry group in principle could have Grassmann-odd directions? Yes, in principle.

Comment: Your so called "internal supersymmetry" was the first type discovered by Miyazawa in 1966,  doi=10.1143/PTP.36.1266 and 1968, doi=10.1103/PhysRev.170.1586. The fermionic generators commute with the Lorentz group.

Comment: Could you please also comment on this extract from Binetruy? https://i.imgur.com/LEUcsUq.png Why should Qs necessarily carry a spinorial index? What is wrong about grassman-odd scalars?